# Exposing Vf Page on the Account Object

Tags: visualforce, account, standardcontroller

I am trying to create a simple VF page that creates a Physician's Note on save.

I am having trouble exposing this VF page on the account object since the standard controller is set to `Physicians_note__c`

Physicians Note is a child to the Account.

**Below is my code:**

```
<apex:page StandardController="Physicians_Note__c">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Physician's Note" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField Label="Subjective" value="{!Physicians_Note__c.Subjective__c}" style="width:500px"/>
            <br></br>
            <apex:inputField Label="Objective" value="{!Physicians_Note__c.Objective__c}" style="width:500px"/>
            <br></br>
            <apex:inputField Label="Assessment" value="{!Physicians_Note__c.Assessment__c}" style="width:500px"/>
            <br></br>
            <apex:inputField Label="Plan" value="{!Physicians_Note__c.Plan__c}" style="width:500px"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

[image]

**I am trying to put the VF page on the account page using the Edit page option:**

[image]

Can anyone help me expose this VF page on the account page while still creating the Physician's Note when pressing save?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any page that you want to include in the `Account` layout must use that standard controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
```

If you want to add a child object, you may need to add an extension. The code would look like:

```
public with sharing class AddPhysicianNoteExtension
{
    public Physician_Note__c note { get; private set; }
    public AddPhysicianNoteExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // this constructor must be defined to add the extension to the page
        Id accountId = controller.getId();
        note = new Physician_Note__c(Account__c=accountId);
    }
    public void save()
    {
        // you will have to define this logic
    }
}
```

Then you would add the extension to the page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AddPhysicianNoteExtension">
```

---

As far as that save method is concerned, the most basic implementation would just be:

```
insert note;
```

But it is highly advisable to add some error handling. The simplest approach there would just be:

```
try
{
    insert note;
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.Confirm, 'Record saved!'
    ));
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
}
```

To surface these messages, you will have to add an [`<apex:pageMessages>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) tag and make sure to rerender it on save.

```
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
...
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="msgs" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian, i got the Vf page successfully on the account object.

my last question would be, when i press the save button nothing happens. But when i refresh the page the new record shows in the associated related list (Found underneath the vf component). Can i set it to refresh the page on save so i can show that the record has been created without having to manually refresh?

Comment: You need to have your save button rerender an [`<apex:pageMessages>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) tag.

Comment: @Alex If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Account as standard Controller and your custom controller as an extension. This will then enable you add this page on account object layout.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Physicians_Note__c">
```